# How To Store Array Data in tree node in asp.net TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I want to store object data to `TreeView` node dynamically (while the application is running).  In Windows Form, I use

```
node.tag = ?
```

and it is okay.  I try

```
node.DataItem = something
```

but it is readonly.  So how would I store object data in an ASP.NET TreeView node?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Tag property in ASP.NET TreeNode but You can impliment your own treenode with Tag Property

[How to extend a built-in TreeNode class of the ASP.NET TreeView control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527108)

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CSASPNETInheritingFromTreeNode
{
    public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
    {

        protected override TreeNode CreateNode()
        {
            return new CustomTreeNode(this, false);
        }
    }

    public class CustomTreeNode : TreeNode
    {

        public object Tag { get; set; }

        public CustomTreeNode() : base()
        {
        }

        public CustomTreeNode(TreeView owner, bool isRoot) : base(owner, isRoot)
        {
        }


        protected override void LoadViewState(object state)
        {
            object[] arrState = state as object[];

            this.Tag = arrState[0];
            base.LoadViewState(arrState[1]);
        }


        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object[] arrState = new object[2];
            arrState[1] = base.SaveViewState();
            arrState[0] = this.Tag;

            return arrState;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much :) . I have been searching for this sooo long .. Finally you posted this answer. It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET [TreeNode control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.aspx) is what you're working with now (as opposed to the WinForms one).  There are two relevant properties for you:

`TreeNode.Text` - What is actually displayed on the tree.
`TreeNode.Value` - The underlying value of that node.

You don't want to mess with the `DataItem` property (as you discovered) unless you are binding a datasource to your TreeView (which it doesn't sound like you are doing).  And even then, that is only for getting the value; you can't store anything that way.

Comment: TreeNode.Value is a string property, which does not offer the same flexibility as the tag property on the WinForms treeview